# Manage SSL certs across IIS 7.5 web farm in Windows 2008R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, ssl-certificate

I need to install and config the same SSL certificate across all of my servers.

How can I manage this under IIS 7.5 across our web farm?

I see that the feature is coming in the next version of server and IIS, but that does not help me now.

Comment: Why can't you manually install each certificate onto the machine?

Answer (score 0):

The IIS Web Farm Framework will do it, and do it well.  You don't have to use the load balancing feature and you don't have to have use a different controller server, unless you want to.  It can also sync up all server settings and a whole bunch of other stuff.

http://www.iis.net/download/webfarmframework